# Dimensions vs Scale without affecting animation

Tags: animation, armature, bones, scale, dimensions

## Before the issue:

For the past few weeks I've been doing a few animations on a Character with an Armature, with a pretty good certainty that I had the scale at 1.

Turns out, somehow in the middle of the process, (despite not being changed in size / scale since its creation) the Armature ended up with a similar scale to the character - which was set to about 0.10.

Probably happened automatically during the parenting and I didn't notice it?

I've been trying to come up with solutions to change their scales back to 1 without affecting the animations and I recently found out that

- using <kbd>ALT</kbd> **+** <kbd>S</kbd> does exactly just that.

### Current issue:

However...

I now have the issue of having - although properly scaled meshes and armature - really huge dimensions on both.

If I would export this into UE4 it would be ridiculously large.

On the same note, although having the same size and (*now*) scale, my Armature has nearly 13m in height while my mesh has only near 3?

Question 1: Does this difference in dimensions affect anything during the export?
Question 2: How can I change these dimensions without affecting the animations in any way?

Would really appreciate the help!

**TL;DR:** I've tried Applying Scale. Scale and Rotation too.

But I only found <kbd>ALT</kbd> **+** <kbd>S</kbd> to help with the Scale without affecting my animations and now I have huge dimensions on my mesh and my armature.

**How do I change these without ruining the animations?**

Answer (score 0):

apply **scale** and **rotation**

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

**las dimensiones no se cambian, solo puede cambiar la escala**

[image: CTRL + A]

Comment: Unfortunately using this method changes my poses and therefore my animations :( That's why I'm asking for help here haha

Comment: in your question you never mention this, so you are answered according to what your question says, and your question is not understood, besides you are asking a lot of questions when you only have to ask individual questions

Comment: Ask your question to understand what you are looking for

Comment: I did say I spent hours on this and that the only way I found to change the scale without affecting the animations was by using Alt+S, though. I just assumed that was clear enough to say that I've tried everything related to the scale ^^" If that wasn't clear, I apologize.
My problem is the dimensions of the object and the armature.

Comment: no problem I also had it but it was not difficult to solve it and just use what I show
I did not have animations even though it was easy for me to unclog the armor and apply scales and re-match the armor, that gave me a clean solution that would be the most recommended

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found this thread on a subreddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/8eqx0g/armature_apply_scale_without_destroy_the/

--

Doesn't the scale of the armature need to be 1,1,1 for it to be exported correctly onto an engine?

Comment: I had tried this, but I was assuming the scale of the armature should be 1 as well, so I dismissed it. Was I wrong?